# Keycloak Identity provider post-broker-login throwing error

Tags: keycloak

Actually I am doing setup of **identity provider using oidc**, followed [this documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker_oidc).
After authentication of external provider I'am getting below error for post-broker-login.

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameter: username"}
```

and I'am thinking that the issue is with the returned data from the external provider.
External provider userinfo endpoint not returning any username instead returning email So I tried to configure mapper to claim email as username as you can see in the screenshot.
Can anyone please help me out?

[image]

When I trace the keycloak log got below

```
[0m[33m06:52:04,179 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-5) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_POST_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=Calipressed-1, clientId=account-console, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=user_not_found, identity_provider=zaikio, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/account/#/, identity_provider_identity=test@testing.com, code_id=8f2e65c-a612-4982-8370-e9a243668e61, authSessionParentId=8f2e65cd-a612-4982-8370-e9a243668e6, authSessionTabId=5L1mxMCoEZ
```

Update ::

When I set both flow as browser, It first authenticate with external idp and then redirect to post-broker-login page (keycloak) and when I tried to login with same username, password it throws error that `Invalid username or password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Identity Provider Configuration set the field *First Login Flow* as 'first broker login' and leave the *Post Login Flow* field empty (unless you really need additional verification of each user authenticated with that IDP).

Additionally, you can also try to create at the Identity Provider configuration a Mapper of type *Username Template importer*.

In the *template* field you can use: `${CLAIM.email}`, and for the target field you can use `LOCAL`.